# Rethinkdb orderBy random

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I'm trying to get the result returned from a table to be in random order.

I have tried:

```
r.db( "db" ).table( "table" ).orderBy( function() { return r.random(); } );
```

but that just gives me the following error:

`e: Sorting by a non-deterministic function is not supported in:
r.db("db").table("table").orderBy(function(var_33) { return r.random(); })`

Also I have read in the rethink documentation that this is not supported. This is from the rethinkdb orderBy documentation:

`Sorting functions passed to orderBy must be deterministic. You cannot, for instance, order rows using the random command. Using a non-deterministic function with orderBy will raise a ReqlQueryLogicError.`

Any suggestions on how to get this to work? Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, it is removed now.

Comment: The `sample` method will return documents in a random order